# PHP - How to add decimals , . to my number without adding 00?

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

I do have prices in my DB and want to add . and , to display them on my site.

I know number_format but if I use it like this
`number_format($ctotal, 2, ".", ",");`

it will add 2 additional 00 at the end.

Example:

```
DB: 100000
Now: 100,000.00
Should look like this: 1,000.00
```

Looks like an easy task but can't find the solution ...

Thanks!

Comment: how can one hundred thousand equal one thousand? is there a specific reason?

Comment: Simple mathematics: `number_format($ctotal / 100, 2, ".", ",");`

Comment: @anantkumarsingh - I suspect it's being stored like this to avoid the risk of floating point errors, precisely because it is a monetary value

Comment: @Fred-ii- Probably storing cents as integers instead of numbers as floats to avoid rounding errors associated to floats.

Comment: @jeroen I can tell you paid attention in math class ;-) and/or economics class.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ummmmmmmmm

Comment: @jeroen I'll bet Mark (Baker) was sitting right next to you in class and you probably didn't even know it ;-)

Comment: and yes, it is a monetary value and stored like this to avoid any risk of floating point errors. @anantkumarsingh

Comment: @Fred-ii- I Should've paid more attention during English. Well, too late to edit now...

Comment: @jeroen it's not too late however, to pick up where you left off ;-) I on the other hand, did better in English than in my native tongue haha. *Ironic isn't it?*. Bizarro.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not really, happened to me as well. Every time :-)

Comment: @Oliver please mark and up-vote the answer for others help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off storing the numbers in a format that is preferable to math in the database without the floating-point issues, then formatting the numbers at the time of display. It will allow you to use the source data for calculations without needing to reformat the numbers (again) or encountering other problems with floating-point calculations.